# extracting a field from HTML with BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup4 for the first time, and get stuck with a something that must be straightforward. I have an Element Tag which looks like this:

```
<td class="stage" data-value="phase3">\n                                    
\n    Phase 3\n<svg height="5" viewbox="1 1 95 5" width="95" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">\n<g fill="none" transform="translate(1 1 
)">\n<rect fill="#911C36" height="5" rx="2" width="15"></rect>\n<rect 
fill="#D6A960" height="5" rx="2" width="15" x="16"></rect>\n<rect 
fill="#E7DE6F" height="5" rx="2" width="15" x="32"></rect>\n<rect fill="#ddd" 
height="5" rx="2" width="15" x="48"></rect>\n<rect fill="#ddd" height="5" 
rx="2" width="15" x="64"></rect>\n<rect fill="#ddd" height="5" rx="2" 
width="15" x="80"></rect>\n</g>\n</svg> </td>
```

I want to extract value "phase3" from the "data-value" field and a list of fill colors, like

```
[ "#911C36", "#D6A960", ... ]
```

What are the right queries for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[BS docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-keyword-arguments) specify that passing `True` matches anything regardless of value. Something like this should work:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


soup = BeautifulSoup("""
<td class="stage" data-value="phase3">\n                                    
\n    Phase 3\n<svg height="5" viewbox="1 1 95 5" width="95" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">\n<g fill="none" transform="translate(1 1 
)">\n<rect fill="#911C36" height="5" rx="2" width="15"></rect>\n<rect 
fill="#D6A960" height="5" rx="2" width="15" x="16"></rect>\n<rect 
fill="#E7DE6F" height="5" rx="2" width="15" x="32"></rect>\n<rect fill="#ddd" 
height="5" rx="2" width="15" x="48"></rect>\n<rect fill="#ddd" height="5" 
rx="2" width="15" x="64"></rect>\n<rect fill="#ddd" height="5" rx="2" 
width="15" x="80"></rect>\n</g>\n</svg> </td>
""", "html.parser")

colors = [x["fill"] for x in soup.findAll("rect", {"fill": True})]
data_vals = [x["data-value"] for x in soup.findAll("td", {"data-value": True})]

print(colors)
print(data_vals)
```

Output:

```
['#911C36', '#D6A960', '#E7DE6F', '#ddd', '#ddd', '#ddd']
['phase3']
```

Comment: Thank you, that's really helpful. Want to clear up something for myself: this piece of code works fine as a standalone, but in my table parser I first findAll 'tr' tags, then in a given 'tr' find all 'td' columns like columns = tr.findAll('td'), and only then I try to apply your code to, say, column[2], which is as above. So there I'm doing findAll not on a BeautifulSoup object, but on a bs4.element.Tag object. And then suddenly findAll can't find any attributes and "data-val" query produces an empty list, while "colors" still work. Do you have any suggestions why this happens?

Comment: I can't tell without seeing your code, but if you have an individual element, you can access the attribute like a dict: `fill_elems = soup.findAll(True, {"fill": True})
print(fill_elems[2]["fill"])` outputs: `#D6A960`. Keep in mind that `findAll()` returns a `ResultSet` object.